# Question regarding multiple currencies

Tags: multi-currency, currency

We do not maintain multiple currencies and we do not wish to do that at this time. What we would like to do is to provide our users with the ability to choose a currency from a picklist dropdown (Chosen Currency) and then to have a field (Calculated Revenue) calculated and displaying the revenue amount in that chosen currency.

It seems like I would be able to do this if I just have a currency table which I can reference which is maintained.

I've been looking into currency apps to maintain a table and they all seem to be based upon the notion that my org would be setup to manage currencies, which we are not.

Are we best off setting up to manage currencies if we are going to attempt to do this ?

Comment: Take a look at [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000IAXwBUAX/improve-currency-support-to-better-support-packaged-currency-handling) where I discuss various limitations for currency handling that I would like to see removed.

Answer (score 1):

Multicurrency is designed to make it easy to use multiple currencies as opposed to building something from scratch. For example, currency fields now display the currency designator, users can report on amounts in either corporate currency or their own locally selected currency, and so on. Of course, the downside is that this can't be turned off once you turn it on, so test it out in a Sandbox first, but I'd suggest that you'd likely be better off actually enabling the feature.